# The Matlab event function doesn't stop the integration

Tags: matlab, solver

I have a ode system that I solve with Matlab. I want to find the steady state of the system and to do so, I use the event function as described [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4858-steady-state-criterion).

But some times, the solver doesn't stop even if the criterium is achieved.
For example, if you solve the following system with `x0 = 10` the solver will stop before 2000 but with `x0 = 0.0001` it won't.

The event function (eventfun_t.m)

```
function [x,isterm,dir] = eventfun_t(t,y)
    dy = test_systeme(t,y);
    x = norm(dy) - 1e-3;

    isterm = 1;
    dir = 0;  %or -1, doesn't matter
end
```

The system (test_systeme.m)

```
function dx = test_systeme(t,x)
    v = x./(x+1);
    dx = -v;
end
```

Solve the system

```
x0 = 10;
eventfonction = @(t,y) eventfun_t(t,y);
optionsode=odeset('Events',eventfonction);
[t x]=ode15s(@(t,x) test_systeme(t,x),[0 2000],x0,optionsode);
```

I suppose it's because with `x0 = 0.0001` `norm(dy)` is already lower than 1e-3 but in that case, how can I stop the solver without checking by myself ?

Answer (score 1):

The events function checks for sign changes in value.  So if value(t=0)<0 and value(0 < t < t_end)<0, then it will never trigger.

A way I've gotten around this is to use conditional statements:

```
value = 1;
if norm(dy)<1e-3&&t~=0
   value = -1;
end
```

The t~=0 statement allows value to change sign after the first step if it's already less than the theshold.